# mySQL not returning an array into angularJS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to retrieve the data stored in a mySQL table with a PHP script. I want this data to be returned as an array because I then loop through it in my AngularJS app and conduct various transformations etc. I am getting the data out just fine, but it is returned as just one item in an array i.e. each row is not returned as a separate item of the array. My code as it stands is:

**PHP Get Request**

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM user_details';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare( $sql );

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

$json = json_encode( $result );

echo $json;

Database::disconnect();


?>
```

**Angular Controller**

```
$scope.userprofiles = [];
$http.get('php/getUserDetails.php')
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.userprofiles = data;
});
```

I also run some tests to see what the issue is. Specifically, I see if the variable is an array with:

```
$scope.varcheck = $scope.userprofiles.constructor === Array;
```

This returns true. And then I check the length of the array with:

```
$scope.numRecords = $scope.userprofiles.length;
```

This returns 0.

If anyone had any thoughts it would be a great help.

I also have an issue that if a "/" or a "'" is stored in the database it throws the get request. I assume that it is exiting early. If anyone knew about this it would be great too!

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: You can use `typeof` to get data type.

Comment: Hi Vineet. When I try typeof it returns that the data is an object, not an array. It seems that the json_encode in the php is turning the array into an object rather than an array. Do you know how to have it come out as an array of objects rather than just a single object?

Comment: Hi. So I found out what the issue is. I was trying to access $scope.userprofiles outside of the .then function. So I could put all of my code inside the of the .then function. But this seems like a rather inelegant solution. Do you know if there is another?

Answer (score 0):

$http methods return a promise, which can't be iterated, so you have to attach the results to the scope variable through the callbacks:

```
$scope.userprofiles = []; 
$http.get('php/getUserDetails.php')
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.userprofiles = response.data;
});
```

Hope it may help you :-)

Comment: Hi Vineet. Thanks for the reply. I have tried that and found that it only half works. It will work for something like an ng-repeat or filter. However, it would not work if you wanted to run a for loop for example as it is not recognising the data as an array. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi Vineet. Thanks again for getting back to me. I have tried the second option. But it is still coming up as array length is 0. The result now has the syntax [[{...}]]. It is very odd!

Comment: Hi Vineet. Still not working unfortunately :( I am not sure if I am doing something stupid further up the chain e.g. in the PHP? Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: Also, I copied and pasted the php url data directly into the application and then run the same tests. In this scenario it worked with an array of above 0. However, the get request still does not work. It seems like the $http get request is inserting the data into one data array?